# Transforming big dataframe in more sensible form

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

Dataframe consist of 3 rows: **wine_id**, **taste_group** and and evaluated matching **score** for each of that group:

| wine_id | taste_group | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | tree_fruit | 87 |
| 22 | citrus_fruit | 98 |
| 22 | tropical_fruit | 17 |
| 22 | earth | 8 |
| 22 | microbio | 6 |
| 22 | oak | 7 |
| 22 | vegetal | 1 |

How to achieve to make a **separate column for each taste_group** and to list scores in rows?
Hence this:

| wine_id | tree_fruit | citrus_fruit | tropical_fruit | earth | microbio | oak | vegetal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 87 | 98 | 17 | 8 | 6 | 7 | 1 |

There are 13 taste groups overall, along with more than 6000 Wines.
If the wine doesn't have a score for taste_group row takes value 0.

I used

```
length(unique(tastes$Group))
length(unique(tastes$Wine_Id))
```

in R to question basic measures.
How to proceed to wanted format?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your dataframe is named `tastes`, you'll want something like:

```
library(tidyr)

tastes %>%
    # Get into desired wide format
    pivot_wider(names_from = taste_group, values_from = score, values_fill = 0)
```

Comment: instead of the `mutate`  use the parameter `values_fill = 0` ie `tastes %>% pivot_wider(names_from = taste_group, values_from = score, values_fill = 0)` after which we can upvote

Comment: Nifty! However some values are in vector shape c(5,5)? Any idea why? @Onyambu

Comment: @stepski011 thats because they hasve the same ID values. ie same `wine_id` and same `taste_group`. You could summarize them depending on what you want. eg by summing them, finding the mean etc. just add `values_fn = sum`

Comment: @Onyambu I see that last function provides the sum calculation - but not the one that I need. There is a problem with output: after pivot_wider function from above I get  Error: Can't convert <double> to <list>. with couple warning messages considering values_fn. How to return only dataframe with score values?

Comment: @stepski011 sorry cant tell without the data.

Answer (score 2):

In `R`, this is called as the long-to-wide reshaping, you can also use `dcast` to do that.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- fread("
wine_id taste_group score
22  tree_fruit  87
22  citrus_fruit    98
22  tropical_fruit  17
22  earth   8
22  microbio    6
22  oak 7
22  vegetal 1
")

dcast(dt, wine_id ~ taste_group, value.var = "score")

#wine_id citrus_fruit earth microbio   oak tree_fruit tropical_fruit vegetal
#     <int>        <int> <int>    <int> <int>      <int>          <int>   <int>
#      22           98     8        6     7         87             17       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `reshape`:

```r
wide_df <- reshape(
     my_data, 
     timevar="taste_group", 
     v.names = "score", 
     idvar = "wine_id", 
     direction = "wide"
)
```